# Executing functions for multiple directories using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I would like the user to select 2 directories, each directory having their own defined algorithms. For example: *First_Directory* will add a column to all shapefiles in the chosen directory; *Second_Directory* will delete a column to all shapefiles in the chosen directory.

When selecting one directory and leaving the other blank, i.e. only *First_Directory* and leaving *Second_Directory* blank, the algorithms defined for *First_Directory* work fine and vice versa.

However when selecting for both, it seems that only *First_Directory* is processed. What I would like is, ofcourse, for both directories to be processed sequentially.

The code below is merely trying to show the logic, it's the IF statement that I am concerned about (whether or not it's even required in the first place!)

```
##Test=name
##First_Directory=folder
##Second_Directory=folder

path_1 = First_Directory
path_2 = Second_Directory
path = path_1 or path_2

os.chdir(path)

def First(path_1):
#Do some processing

def Second(path_2):
#Do some other processing

if path_1:
    score_1(path_1)
elif path_2:
   score_2(path_2)
elif path_1 and path_2:
    score_1(path_1)
    score_2(path_2)
else:
    pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not really GIS related.  The problem is your condition (first if and first elif) are always being meet if either of the directories are being selected, then the code jumps out of the conditional statement.

You could switch the order of the conditions to:

```
if path_1 and path_2:
   score_1(path_1)
   score_2(path_2)
elif path_1:
   score_1(path_1)
elif path_2:
   score_2(path_2)
else:
   pass
```